# How to divide the column in equal size in table

Tags: tables

below is my code snippet. I want to make the size of all column equal. The column "XYZ" is not coming in same size with others. The same code works with `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`  class file.

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{bm,array}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2em}}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
head &\multicolumn{2}{|c}{First method} &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Second method} &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Third method} \\
\hline
 0 & A & XYZ & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{CDE} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{FGH} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{JKL}  &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{MNO}\\
\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&8&9&0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: Off-topic: There should be no need to load the `latexsym` package: It hasn't changed since 1998, and it should only be used by people who still use LaTeX2.09 rather than LaTeX2e; the latter has been the "main" LaTeX format since 1994... The package `amssymb` -- which you're already loading -- provides its own definitions of the 11 (yep, only 11) symbols defined in `latexsym`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer works with the `llncs.cls` document class file extracted from `llncs2e.zip`, which I downloaded from http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs/lncs+authors?SGWID=0-40209-0-0-0.)

I suggest you (a) switch to a `tabularx` environment (with width set to `\textwidth`) and (b) use a centered version of the `X` column type instead of a fixed-width `p` column.

Fortunately for you, the `llncs` document class uses an unusually small default value for the parameter `\tabcolsep` (1.4pt, vs. the general default value of 6pt), making further adjustments to `\tabcolsep` unnecessary.

You also need to change `\multicolumn{2}{|c}{First method}` to `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{First method}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}
\usepackage{bm,amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx} % <-- new
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % <-- modified
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{11}{C|}}
\hline
head &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{First method} 
     &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Second method} 
     &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Third method} \\
\hline
0 & A & XYZ 
 &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{CDE} 
 &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{FGH} 
 &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{JKL}  
 &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{MNO}\\
\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, prompted by a follow-up comment by the OP: If you need to permit line wrapping in the combined cells, you can do so by replacing all

```
\multicolumn{n}{c|}
```

parts with

```
\multicolumn{n}{>{\hsize=n\hsize}C|}
```

where "`n`" is either `2` or `4`. For instance:

[image]

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % provide a bit of visual "breathing space"
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{11}{C|}}
\hline
head &\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{First method} 
     &\multicolumn{4}{>{\hsize=4\hsize}C|}{Second method} 
     &\multicolumn{4}{>{\hsize=4\hsize}C|}{Third method} \\
\hline
0 & AA BB CC & UV WX YZ  
 &\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{CDE} 
 &\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{FGH} 
 &\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{JKL}  
 &\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}C|}{MNO}\\
\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the code is working and now I want to make the cells a bit wider. what command should I use

Comment: @M.kalita - Please explain what you mean by "I want to make the cells a bit wider". The overall width of the `\tabularx` environment is set to `\textwidth`; you therefore can't make the cells wider without making the table exceed its permissible maximum width. Are you maybe thinking of switching from portrait mode to landscape mode?

Comment: Okay sir, I got it. In my actual code, the column heading length is more than i have shown in my demo code. My problem could be solved by writing the column heading in multiple lines. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @M.kalita - Thanks for providing this clarification. I've posted an addendum to show explicitly how automatic line wrapping may be enabled in the combined cells.